# an efficient query to import data to oracle sql developer 4.1.3.20 version

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import the CSV files to oracle table. Not through the import wizard.

Is there an efficient way to import automatically?like Bulk import in sql server of microsoft.
there should be..

Please give step by step options.

Comment: Try using SQL Loader.

Comment: You can also look at external tables, but it might be worth stepping back and seeing if you can use datapump export/import rather than using CSV text files.

Answer (score 2):

Sql*loader is the probably the most comparable client utility to sql server bulk import. So an 'efficient' method would be to use SQL Developer and the sql*loader client utility. SQL Developer's data import wizard will help you setup the files for sql*loader utility to use. Rather than re-iterate the details, here's a great post on this...
http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/

Comment: Thanks Beege. I have used the link to create 3 files. CTL,SH and a BAT file using the process. It did not create a log file though. While executing the BAT, it runs in a sec, nothing happens. I cant even see what it reads. Nothing is loading into the table though..I have tried this many times now.

Comment: the .bat file won't do anything if you don't have an Oracle Client installed - that's where you get the SQL*Loader program from

Comment: Yep. And the oracle 'instant client' doesn't contain the sqlldr.exe program either. You will need install a "normal" version of the oracle client. (Or, unsupported, copy it from an install that does have it.)

Comment: I have oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3.20 and and express edition installed, this wont suffice the requirements? please guide.

Comment: Yes, the Oracle express edition should suffice as it contains the sqlldr.exe Among other considerations, your PATH needs to reference the location of this executable. SO isn't really the place for a "how-to" discussion, so last update from me.